# Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe' in Ode solver

Tags: scipy, ode, solver, numerical-integration, odeint

I have a function which needs to be simulated by using a scipy 'odeint' solver. I am providing initial values as an numpy array which contains 13 parameters which are different in sizes. Also, all are integer values. But, I am getting an error msg as "Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'".

If I try to use dtype=float or astype.float, then it gives me a new error as "setting an array element with a sequence."

Can someone help me to find a way to fix this problem?. Highly appreciate if you can show a solution by mentioning codes as well.

Comment: what does `odeint` say about initial values?  I suspect it wants a 1d array of floats.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html

It says only the initial value should be an array. Nothing more about it.

Comment: You would have to show the initial value to say more, but the second error is rather specific. One or more of the entries in the list are arrays, not integers. It might help locate the error if you print the initial value directly before the error location, or set a breakpoint there in a debugger to inspect that list.

Comment: Ok, but it uses a compiled function (`odepac`).  That won't work with object dtype array with references to other python objects.  Did you get an error message with traceback?  I should also complain about missing code.

Comment: You can't turn an object dtype array with elements of differing size into float dtype array.